# Minecraft region files corrupted

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Back in version 1.6.4 of Minecraft, I started building a server that went on for three years. I had it in a server host online and they just quite without even asking me to backup the map (they said they emailed me, checked 1000x times and nothing was there), and so I was very sad that I lost my map but did notice that I had made a backup. When I checked the backup, the seed is the same, the coordinates all go to the same spot but there are no constructions. Everything I built is just gone. I know for sure that this is the backup because of the quantity of the players that played in it.
As you can see in the folder region, there are a lot of files, and I just don't know how to deal with them (tried to open them in a "region file opener"(?) but I think some are broken and I don't know why); (MCEdit crashes if I try to open the map in it).
When I tried to open the server on a recent version it says this:

https://justpaste.it/1epm7

I have tried a chunk fixer and some other things but nothings has worked yet. I have tried opening it in the right version but still nothing in the map appears.
[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7ra5j8z4m31sujc/VBBACKUp.rar) is a download of the backup. Please help me to recover this map.

The coordinates where the constructions were at was around 600 100 600.

What if it is not the region files that are corrupted but the level.dat itself? Can someone check that out?

When I open the region files with NBTExplorer it says "not a valid region file".

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the files and most of them are either corrupted or have been modified in some way. While most of the files are from 2014, there are 3 files from 2017 in the archive that are not corrupted. Unfortunately, they contain pristine terrain without any structures. One of these 3 files is from region 1.1 where the coordinates 600, 600 are. There are no buildings there. It is possible that the chunks were regenerated by the chunk fixer you mentioned. Either way, there is no way to restore buildings in that region. Do you happen to have the original files before the use of chunk fixer?